# What is a fast algorithm to compute the primorial $P_{n}$ given the primorial $P_{n+1}$?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, entropy, primorial

This question is related to my other question regarding entropy with respect to a given multiplicative function ( [Limit for entropy of prime powers defined by multiplicative arithmetic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371244/limit-for-entropy-of-prime-powers-defined-by-multiplicative-arithmetic-function) ). Call a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  **irreversible with respect to a multiplicative function $f\ge 1$** if $H_f(a_n) < H_f(a_{n+1})$ where $H_f$ is the entropy with respect to $f$. Let $P_n$ be the $n$-th primorial. Then it is not difficult to show, that the sequence $(P_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is irreversible with respect to every multiplicative function $f \ge 1$. Hence this suggests, that given $P_{n+1}$ for a large $n$, then it will be difficult to compute $P_n$.
So this motivates the question:

Is there a known fast algorithm to compute the primorial $P_{n}$ given the primorial $P_{n+1}$ (for a large value of $n$)? (We observe only the value of $P_{n+1}$ not the value of $n$)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "fast".  The number of digits in $P_n$ is about $n \log n$, so merely being **given** $P_n$ is much slower than any modern algorithm for primality testing on integers close to $p_n$.

Comment: @ErickWong: Let's say "fast" compared to the number of digits of $P_n$.

Comment: @staclExchangeUser I think that misses my point.  Computing $P_n$ given $P_{n+1}$ is equivalent to computing $p_{n+1}$ given $P_{n+1}$.  Now, it only takes about $O(\sqrt{n})$ to compute $p_{n+1}$ given $n$, but it takes over $\Omega(n)$ time just to look at $P_{n+1}$ or to print out $P_n$.  So it's a bit meaningless to say that it's easy or hard to compute $P_n$ when the "hardest" part of doing so is just how long it takes to spell out the digits.  It means that making use of $P_{n+1}$ is almost purely a liability and not an advantage.

Comment: @ErickWong: Ok, but given $P_{n+1}$ how will you infer $n$? What is the time to find out $n$?

Comment: That is a good question that gets to the heart of my objection.  One can take logs to estimate the value of $p_{n+1}$ and then use a binary search to look for the largest prime dividing $P_{n+1}$.  The search can probably be done in about $O(\sqrt{n})$ steps if we are careful with PNT estimates, but the expensive part of each step is just *testing* $P_{n+1}$ for divisibility by a given prime which is $\Omega(n \log n)$ time.  Again, the sheer size of $P_{n+1}$ is the only thing making it hard, and the optimal algorithm just minimizes how often we look at $P_{n+1}$ — it's a liability.

Comment: @ErickWong: So, it can be done in time $\Omega(\sqrt{n}n\log(n))$? I understand your concerns about the size of $P_n$, but I am just curious, how fast one can find $n$ given $P_{n+1}$. So in terms of the number of digits of $P_n$, it can be done fast. But in terms of the number of digits of $n$, it can not be done fast? Did I understand that correct?

Comment: Yes, it can certainly be done in time polynomial in the number of digits of $P_n$ (I missed a factor in estimating $O(\sqrt{n})$ steps for the binary search, it should just be $O(n)$ steps).  But in terms of the number of digits of $n$, it is fairly hopeless unless we have an extremely accurate error estimate for the Chebyshev function $\theta(n)$, much stronger than what we get from Riemann hypothesis.  Note that it is much faster to find $n$ given the prime $p_{n+1}$ rather than the primorial, though still exponential in the number of digits.