# A question on entropy of natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, inequality, entropy, conjectures, perfect-numbers

This question is more of a conjecture, but I am not posting it to mathoverflow, since I am not a professional mathematician and I do not know if it is research related:
Let $n=p^{a} s$, $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $n$, $v_p(n) = a$, $n\equiv 1(2)$,$\sigma(n) = 2n$. Then we must have $p>2$. Let $m=2^a s $. Then we have
$$\sigma(m)= \sigma(2^a)\sigma(s)= \frac{\sigma(2^a)\sigma(n)}{\sigma(p^a)}$$.
Since $2<p$ we have $H(2^a) < H(p^a)$ where $H$ is the entropy of $n$ defined here: [Entropy of a natural number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369779/entropy-of-a-natural-number). It follows that:
$$H(n) = H(p^a s) = H(p^a)+H(s) > H(2^a) + H(s) = H(m) = \log(\sigma(m))-\frac{1}{\sigma(m)}\sum_{d|m}{d \log(d)} = \log(\frac{\sigma(2^a)\sigma(n)}{\sigma(p^a)})-\frac{1}{\sigma(m)}E(m)$$,
where $E(k) = \sum_{d|k} {d \log(d)}$. Since $\log(x) \ge 1 - 1/x$ we have

$$ H(n) > H(m) = \log(\sigma(n))+\log(\frac{\sigma(2^a)}{\sigma(p^a)})-\frac{E(m)}{\sigma(m)}\ge\log(\sigma(n))+1-\frac{\sigma(p^a)}{\sigma(2^a)}-\frac{E(m)}{\sigma(m)}$$
which is equal to:
$$\log(\sigma(n))+1-\frac{\sigma(n)}{\sigma(m)}-\frac{E(m)}{\sigma(m)}$$
If we can prove that, the last quantity is greater than or equal to $\log(\sigma(n))-\frac{E(n)}{\sigma(n)}= H(n)$, we would get the contradiction:
$$H(n)>H(m) \ge H(n)$$
So we have to prove that:
$$1 - \frac{\sigma(n)}{\sigma(m)}-\frac{E(m)}{\sigma(m)} \ge - \frac{E(n)}{\sigma(n)}$$
We have the following identities:
$$E(m) = \sigma(2^a)E(s)+\sigma(s)E(2^a)$$
$$E(n) = \sigma(p^a)E(s)+\sigma(s)E(p^a)$$
Furthermore one can show that:
$$E(p^a) = p \log(p) \frac{p^{a+1}-1-(a+1)p^a(p-1)}{(p-1)^2}$$
which can be applied to compute $E(2^a)$.

So my question is if somebody can help me prove the inequality above or show an "example" where it fails, if this is not too much to ask.

Comment: Have you tried to determine whether your required inequality holds, by using a Computer Algebra System (CAS) such as WolframAlpha or Mathematica, given your other formulas for $E(m)$ and $E(n)$?  I mean, it should be a relatively straightforward task to type it into the CAS, right?

Comment: At any rate, +1 for an interesting question and a potentially feasible approach to showing that certain forms of odd perfect numbers do not exist.

Comment: Posting a (partial) answer in a bit.

Comment: I have posted what appears to be a complete answer to your earlier comment, @stackExchangeUser.  I am surprised that said comment has now been deleted.  At any rate, my answer presupposes the truth of the content of that comment.

Comment: Thanks again! Yes you are right with the comment. It was wrong. But thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You require that
$$\frac{E(p^a)}{\sigma(p^a)} \geq \frac{E(2^a)}{\sigma(2^a)}.$$

Assuming my calculations are correct, this inequality simplifies to:
$$\frac{p\log p}{p - 1} - p\log p\frac{(a+1){p^a}}{p^{a+1} - 1} \geq 2\log 2 - 2\log 2\frac{(a+1){2^a}}{2^{a+1} - 1}$$

I asked [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20%5B(p%20Log%20p)%2F(p%20-%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201)%20-%20(p%20Log%20p)%20((a%20%2B%201)%20(p%5Ea))%2F(p%5E(a%20%2B%201)%20-%201)%20%3E%3D%20%20%20%202%20Log%202%20-%202%20Log%202%20((a%20%2B%201)%20(2%5Ea))%2F(2%5E(a%20%2B%201)%20-%201)%20,%20p%5D) for the solutions of this inequality for $p$, it gave the following inequality plot:

[image]

This inequality plot can be interpreted to mean that the solutions are given by the sets of inequalities:

$$p \geq 2, a \leq 0$$

or

$$p \leq 2, a \geq 0.$$

Since neither of these two sets of inequalities satisfy the conditions of the problem, I am led to believe that your conjectured inequality does not hold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!